# Ubuntu is slower than tortoise

Tags: 20.04, screen, cpu, crash

**I installed ubuntu 20.04 (64bit) not more than 1.5 month ago. Now it has became slower as tortoise. It hangs a lot. Apps are also crashing**

*After running `top` in my terminal in case you need it*

```
y@MackbookPro:~$ top

top - 21:48:55 up 4 days,  6:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.76, 1.11, 1.63
Tasks: 234 total,   1 running, 233 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.1 us,  4.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.2 id,  0.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.7 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   3804.6 total,    118.1 free,   2892.8 used,    793.6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,    317.7 free,   1730.3 used.    602.9 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                  
   1403 pronay    20   0 4521120 114116  40336 S  14.0   2.9  81:59.17 gnome-shell                                                              
  51842 pronay    20   0  413100  51088  38876 S   7.3   1.3   0:03.87 gnome-terminal-                                                          
   1264 pronay    20   0 3587844   8800   5436 S   2.0   0.2  24:56.36 pulseaudio                                                               
  14657 pronay    20   0 2949944 118612  52960 S   1.0   3.0  20:39.63 Web Content                                                              
   5991 pronay    20   0 4136964 393300 100156 S   0.7  10.1 114:35.70 firefox                                                                  
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   1:57.73 rcu_sched                                                                
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:07.29 ksoftirqd/1                                                              
  14703 pronay    20   0 5125348  31408  14760 S   0.3   0.8   5:48.28 code                                                                     
  14803 pronay    20   0 4590016  35108  15336 S   0.3   0.9   3:30.92 code                                                                     
  14877 pronay    20   0 1165444    120    120 S   0.3   0.0   1:32.62 cpptools                                                                 
  41626 pronay    20   0 2533508  70632  42444 S   0.3   1.8   1:24.99 Web Content                                                              
  49321 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:04.38 kworker/0:2-events                                                       
  49776 pronay    20   0 3204652 274696 136104 S   0.3   7.1   2:35.92 Web Content                                                              
  49990 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:02.21 kworker/u8:2-events_unbound                                              
  50304 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:01.66 kworker/1:2-events                                                       
  51854 pronay    20   0   20964   3976   3204 S   0.3   0.1   0:00.24 top                                                                      
  51863 pronay    20   0   20988   4000   3208 R   0.3   0.1   0:00.14 top                                                                      
      1 root      20   0  167804   5864   3568 S   0.0   0.2   0:23.03 systemd                                                                  
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 kthreadd                                                                 
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                   
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                               
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                     
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                             
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:08.13 ksoftirqd/0                                                              
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.58 migration/0                                                              
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                            
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                  
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                  
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1
```

after running `lscpu`

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          2
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              2
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      21
Model:                           112
Model name:                      AMD A6-9200 RADEON R4, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G
Stepping:                        0
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1458.383
CPU max MHz:                     2000.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1300.0000
BogoMIPS:                        3992.78
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       64 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full AMD retpoline, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx
                                  mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good acc_power nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmper
                                 f pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm ext
                                 apic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm perfctr
                                 _core perfctr_nb bpext ptsc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate ssbd vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 xsaveopt arat npt lb
                                 rv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmlo
                                 ad vgif overflow_recov
```

after `free`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3895912     2934976      565548       96732      395388      634288
Swap:       2097148     1856300      240848
```

after `uname -a`

```
Linux MackbookPro 5.8.0-44-generic #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
 *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.8.0
       date: 03/01/2018
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 17
       slot: L1 CACHE
       size: 160KiB
       capacity: 160KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 18
       slot: L2 CACHE
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 25
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 [empty]
          product: A1_PartNum0
          vendor: 000000000000
          physical id: 0
          serial: A1_SerialNum0
          slot: DIMM 0
          width: 64 bits
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: M471A5244BB0-CRC
          vendor: 009C360B0000
          physical id: 1
          serial: 124DE38B
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
```

**RAM- 4GB
processor : AMD® A6-9200 radeon r4, 5 compute cores 2c+3g × 2**

pls help me to fix it.

Comment: It seems that you have a memory bottleneck. You should search and find the processes that use a lot of memory. Are you using a 32-bit OS? Please specify the exact version of your Ubuntu system in your original question

Comment: And do you have enough free space in / ?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli 64 bit

Comment: @ChanganAuto MORE THAN 150 GB IS FREE

Comment: Swap: "2048.0 total,    317.7 free,   1730.3 used", RAM: "3804.6 total,    118.1 free,   2892.8 used". You certainly don't have enough RAM for whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: [edit] your question by adding `uname -a`, `sudo lshw -C memory` , and  `free` command outputs.

Comment: @PronaySarker I was just asking because it's pertinent. No need to shout (all caps).

Comment: @FedonKadifeli 1 min... but idk why Its showing I have less than 150 gb free, not sure about free

Comment: @FedonKadifeli done

Comment: 4GB memory is the minimum for Ubuntu desktop. It seems that you have an empty slot to upgrade memory to 8GB. If you are using also a slow hard disk for swap, your system will be quite slow. If you cannot upgrade system memory, you may try to replace the HD with an SSD. See also this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: @muru Now  I am using terminal, visual code, settings and firefox(2 window & 8 tab)

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Its a laptop. Can I add extra 4GB RAM in it?

Comment: It is better to open the laptop and locate the empty memory slot and the full one and buy one more with exactly the same properties with the current memory stick. It seems that you can buy and install this RAM: https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M471A5244BB0-CRC/

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thank you so much Sir :)

Comment: Alternatively, switch to a different flavor of Ubuntu that consumes less RAM, for example, Lubuntu or Kubuntu or Xubuntu. The GNOME desktop itself consumes a lot of RAM, and 4GB would quickly fill up with VSCode and multiple browser tabs.

Comment: You don't have enough swap. Edit your question and show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema What do u mean? didnot get it

Comment: @PronaySarker I'm wanting to know if you implemented my answer, and if it solved the problem.

Comment: @heynnema I do not have enough points. I can not see that check box. Sorry

Comment: @PronaySarker The **grey checkmark icon** is directly to the left of my answer... not my comments. It'll turn **green** when you click on it. Did the answer solve the problem?

Comment: I did :)  @heynnema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SWAP**

With only 4G RAM and Ubuntu, and only 2G swap, you don't have enough swap.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3895912     2934976      565548       96732      395388      634288
Swap:       2097148     1856300      240848
```

**Note**: You may need to add more RAM.

Do `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and if it reports "/swapfile", then do the following to increase your /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: Upvoting in place of OP who wishes to upvote but doesn't have enough points. Also upvoting OP @Pronay to give him more points: ). It's a good Q&A likely to help others with only 4GB of RAM.